# Raspberry Pi 3, bluetooth is not getting connected with HM-10 bluetooth module

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, serial, arduino, troubleshooting

I currently have a Raspberry Pi 3 with built-in bluetooth and some of my work specification require to connect it with HM-10 bluetooth module but I am unable to do so.

I have tried various methods and I have successfully connected it with my android mobile phone using bluetooth serial terminal app but I am unable to do so with HM-10 however bluetooth module gets connected to the Raspberry Pi, but is not serially transmitting data on console and I get a response on command window as:

**Waiting for connection on channel 1**

I am using rfcomm.

Comment: Have you added the bluetooth serial port to /boot/cmdline.txt? Ref. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3

Comment: Try these three steps; https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=158856&p=1032763#p1032763

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is the HM-10 only works using Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy (BLE). BLE is different than the classic Bluetooth, so you can't use the rfcomm serial devices to communicate with the HM-10. Instead you need to use the [gatttool](https://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/get-started-with-bluetooth-low-energy/) to discover the different characteristics of the device and read/write data. 0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is the characteristic the HM-10 uses by default to [read/write up to 20 bytes](https://twitter.com/GBrayUT/status/907490878394064896) at a time (ID can be changed using the AT commands).

Alternatively if you are using a recent version of BlueZ ([5.46](http://www.bluez.org/release-of-bluez-5-46/) or newer) then you can use the [acquire-write and acquire-notify commands of bluetoothctl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392103/using-acquire-write-and-acquire-notify-in-bluetoothctl-for-bluetooth-low-energe) to create file descriptors you can use to read and write data. On my Raspberry Pi 3 I had Ubuntu 16.04.3 installed but `bluetoothctl -v` showed an older version. I came across [this script](https://github.com/muka/go-bluetooth/blob/master/scripts/bluez-install.sh) that worked to install a newer version, and after enabling the experimental features in bluetoothd the acquire commands started working.